# Renderer showing error

Tags: android

i have made an application of textured rotating cube in opengl es 1.0. While converting it into live wallpaper I have implemented Wallpaperservice and all the requisites .

But when i am calling my Renderer class it showing an error "add arguments to match renderer(context)"  so basically in the call i am using the code

```
class MyEngine extends GLEngine {
    BcRenderer renderer;
    public MyEngine() {
        super();
        // handle prefs, other initialization
        renderer = new BcRenderer();
        setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }
}
```

and in BcRenderer class i am using context. So how to remove that error?
help me (I have followed the code of robert green for opengles 1.0 Live wapaper)